# SQL Multiple WHERE Clauses against one table, with CASE statements

Tags: sql, odbc, where-clause, ibm-midrange

I wrote this query and it seems to be working to gather correct results, however, it also takes a VERY long time.  I'm just wondering if there is a way to make it more efficient?
(I understand that it's inefficient because it is creating data tables and joining them back together - I just don't know how to get around it, specifically with the CASE issue included).

I'm working in Excel with an ODBC connection to AS400.  The question marks allow user-entered parameters within Excel cells.

```
with W as
(
  select yr as YEAR, pd as PERIOD, sum(amt1 + amt2 + amt3 + amt4) as SALES
    from TABLE
    group by yr, pd
    order by yr desc, pd desc
), X as
(
  select yr as YEAR, pd as PERIOD, sum(amt1 + amt2 + amt3 + amt4) as BSALES
    from TABLE
    where type = 'B'
    group by yr, pd
    order by yr desc, pd desc
), Y as
(
  select
    CASE WHEN pd = 1 THEN yr - 1 ELSE yr END as YEAR, 
    CASE WHEN pd = 1 THEN 12 ELSE pd - 1 END as PERIOD, 
    SUM(OM) as MODOM
    from TABLE
    group by yr, pd
    order by yr desc, pd desc
), Z as
(
  select
    CASE WHEN pd = 1 THEN yr - 1 ELSE yr END as YEAR, 
    CASE WHEN pd = 1 THEN 12 ELSE pd - 1 END as PERIOD, 
    SUM(BOM) as BMODOM
    from TABLE
    where type = 'B'
    group by yr, pd
    order by yr desc, pd desc
)
select w.YEAR, w.PERIOD, w.SALES, x.BSales, y.MODOM, z.BMODOM
from w inner join x
on w.YEAR = x.YEAR and w.PERIOD = x.PERIOD
inner join y
on w.YEAR = y.YEAR and w.PERIOD = y.PERIOD
inner join z
on w.YEAR = z.YEAR and w.PERIOD = z.PERIOD
where w.YEAR between ? and ? and w.PERIOD between ? and ?
order by YEAR desc, PERIOD desc
```

I had to change the code slightly for privacy purposes, but I believe this all relays correctly.

Example Data:

```
Yr  Pd  Type    Amt OM
18  2   A       45  181
18  2   B       33  163
18  2   A       40  153
18  1   B       39  136
18  1   B       24  142
18  1   B       53  143
18  1   A       41  186
18  1   A       78  197
17  12  A       98  139
17  12  A       54  159
17  12  B       78  181
17  12  B       45  101
17  11  A       28  134
17  11  A       77  192
17  11  A       75  110
17  11  B       60  135
17  11  B       83  170
17  10  B       72  114
17  10  A       26  118
17  10  A       95  111
17  9   A       12  112
17  9   B       14  171
```

Example Results

```
Yr  Pd  Sales   Bsales  MODOM   BMODOM
18  2   118     33      804     421
18  1   235     116     580     282
17  12  275     123     741     305
17  11  323     143     343     114
17  10  193     72      283     171
```

Note that I need SALES at a TOTAL Level, and then at a TYPE B level.  I also need OM at a TOTAL Level, and then also a Type B level - HOWEVER - I need to offset by one period.  So the MODOM is for 17-10 is reflection of the OM total for period 17-9 in the table.  (I hope that make sense).

**EDIT** I have this backward.  The MODOM for 17-10 would actually reflect the OM value for 17-11, not the other way.    Corrected EXPECTED RESULTS.

```
Yr  Pd  Sales   Bsales  MODOM   BMODOM
18  2   118     33      0       0
18  1   235     116     497     163
17  12  275     123     804     421
17  11  323     143     580     282
17  10  193     72      741     305
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You would benefit from "conditional aggregation" instead of querying same table a lot and then relating back together

Comment: I updated with example data / results.   I don't know what Conditional Aggregation is - but I will continue my Google Search endeavor with that set of keywords - thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So using Conditional aggregation you can at least get rid of 2 of your common table expressions which will help.  Not ordering until your final presentation query instead of in each common table expression will help too.  Using an actual date e.g. First of First Month of a Period could help eliminate what the potentially costly case expressions when defining previous period.

There are a few ways of writing this but this will give you an example of conditional aggregation.

And note the LEFT JOIN rather than INNER because your 1st period will always drop off your query if you use INNER

```
WITH PeriodSales AS(
    SELECT
       yr as YEAR
       ,pd AS PERIOD
       ,SUM(amt) as SALES
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN amt END) as BSALES
    FROM
       Table
    GROUP BY
       yr
       ,pd
)
, PreviousPeriod AS 
(
    SELECT
       CASE WHEN pd = 12 THEN yr + 1 ELSE yr END as YEAR
       ,CASE WHEN pd = 12 THEN 1 ELSE pd + 1 END as PERIOD
       ,SUM(OM) as MODOM
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN OM END) as BMODOM
    FROM
       Table
    GROUP BY
       CASE WHEN pd = 12 THEN yr + 1 ELSE yr END
       ,CASE WHEN pd = 12 THEN 1 ELSE pd + 1 END
)

SELECT
    ps.YEAR
    ,ps.PERIOD
    ,ps.SALES
    ,ps.BSALES
    ,pp.MODOM
    ,pp.BMODOM
FROM
    PeriodSales ps
    LEFT JOIN PreviousPeriod pp
    ON ps.YEAR = pp.YEAR
    AND ps.PERIOD = pp.PERIOD
ORDER BY
    ps.YEAR DESC
    ,ps.PERIOD DESC
```

Per your edits, to align to the "Previous Period" to get to the OM amounts you want you will actually want to ADD a period not subtract one in the example I used.  I have tested this and it does work.  There can be many other factors for performance that we cannot discover without knowing more about the tables and execution plans etc.

Comment: OP...Consider encapsulating the statement in a Stored Procedure, UDTF, or a view that you can use from Excel; rather than having the whole query in Excel.

Comment: I had to make up the test data / results for posting, as the actual information cannot be shared.   I did in fact get it backwards in the fictitious data - it should be the other way around.  Period 17-10 MODOM would be reflective of the 17-11 OM values.  My mistake.

Comment: Can you explain why you used the CASE in the second Group By?  As we have already altered that value, can we not just group by YEAR and PERIOD ?

Comment: @Charles - that's outside my authority / ability within my environment.  But thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @MParker the YEAR and PERIOD definitions in the SELECT may be listed physically above the GROUP BY, but they are not available for use in the GROUP BY, because that actually gets processed first.  (See, for example, [What is the order of execution of a SQL Query](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/what-is-the-order-of-execution-of-an-sql-query).)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this @Charles.  I have gotten it to work fully in my specific scenario - but to be honest, I'm not sure it's much faster.  In a scenario where this can take over a minute to refresh in the Excel document, this may have shaved off a second or two (and that could just be timing differences).   BUT - I definitely learned a lot from making it work.  So thank you!